# Cannot resolve keyword 'articles' into field.Choices are: Choices are: author, caption,id etc

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to relate articles for the user.Here are my codes:

**Models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser,PermissionsMixin):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True)
    username =models.CharField(max_length=80,unique=True,default='SOME STRING')

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    objects = UserManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')


class Article(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='articles')
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

**Serializers.py**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    articles_set = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_articles_set(self, user):
        return ArticleViewSerializer(Article.objects.filter(articles__author=user), many=True).data    



    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields  = ('id','email','username','articles_set')

class ArticleViewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = UserSerializer(required=False,read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('id','author','caption')

    def create(self, validated_data):
     return Article.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

**Views.py**

```
class UserView(CreateAPIView):
  queryset = User.objects.all()
  serializer_class = UserSerializer
  permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
  parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser,)

  def get(self, request, format=None):
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer()
        return Response(serializer.data)

  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.save()
            serializer = UserSerializer(user,many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class ArticleView(CreateAPIView):
  queryset = Article.objects.all()
  serializer_class = ArticleViewSerializer
  permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

  def get(self, request, format=None):
        queryset = Article.objects.all()
        serializer = ArticleViewSerializer()
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Now the issue here is that whenever i try to relate article to a user,i face with this problem
`Cannot resolve keyword 'articles' into field. Choices are: author, author_id, caption, comments,  id`
How can i solve this problem?

**Update 1**: I included my views above.It should help right now for the new issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are querying the `Article` model in the wrong way

change

```
Article.objects.filter(articles__author=user)
```

to

```
Article.objects.filter(author=user)
```

Thus, your `UserSerializer` class will become as follows,

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    articles_set = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_articles_set(self, user):
        return ArticleViewSerializer(Article.objects.filter(author=user), many=True).data



    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields  = ('id','email','username','articles_set')
```

Comment: `maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`

Comment: You have a circular dependency between `UserSerializer` and `ArticleViewSerializer`

Comment: Now i get this : `HyperlinkedRelatedField requires the request in the serializer context. Add context={'request': request} when instantiating the serializer.` I am updating the question with my views in it.